# white screen when running the phpMyAdmin 5.2.0 script from another apache (php-fpm) user

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

operating system:          RockyLinux 8
apache version:              2.4.37
php version:                   7.2.24 (cli)
script location:               /var/www/html
phpMyAdmin version:    5.2.0

- chmod permissions on files/folders don't matter (please use default system chmod permissions)
- there are no errors in the Apache/PHP-FPM logs that would indicate this problem

please do the following:

```
  $ sudo useradd -d /var/www/ -m -U -s /sbin/nologin www
```

change the lines in the file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
  User www  
  Group www
```

change the lines in the file /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
  user = www  
  group = www  
  listen.acl_users = www,nginx
```

restart Apache and PHP-FPM

```
  $ sudo systemctl restart httpd  
  $ sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```

open the page in a browser, you will see a white screen
now, set for php-fpm configuration `user` as `apache` and `group` as `apache`

change the lines in the file /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
  user = apache  
  group = apache
```

restart PHP-FPM

```
  $ sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```

now you see the main page of the phpMyAdmin script in a browser

what's the matter here?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was having these exact same symptoms in my Rocky 8 environment. Basically trying to run the entire LAMP service as a user other than "apache", would cause phpMyAdmin to show a blank screen, while all other PHP scripts still worked fine.

**The solution for me was to change the permissions of three folders within /var/lib/php directory:**

/var/lib/php/opcahce
/var/lib/php/session
/var/lib/php/wsdlcache

These were all set to root:apache ownership with file permissions 770 (rwxrwx---).

By modifying the permissions on these three folders to be writable by the new user (non apache) that is running the httpd & php-fpm services, the phpMyAdmin page began working again. In my case I simply changed the ownership to root:newuser ("newuser" being the user running the services rather than apache).

**Environment:**

**Rocky Linux 8.7:** 4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64

**WEB:** Apache/2.4.37 (rocky) OpenSSL/1.1.1k SVN/1.14.1

**PHP:** 7.4.30